# AWS JS SDK - IOT updateCertificate function executes twice with undesireable side effects

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

Using the AWS Javascript SDK (V2), I am seeing unexpected behaviour. Every time I execute either iot.updateCertificate or iot.deleteCertificate, it seems to execute twice. The exact code is:

```
// Deactivate
    console.log("updateCertificate"); 
    params = {
        certificateId: certId,                  /* required */
        newStatus: "INACTIVE"                   /* required */
    };
    await iot.updateCertificate(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(`update err = ${JSON.stringify(err)}, err.stack = ${err.stack}`);     // an error occurred
        else     console.log(`update data = ${data}`);                                             // successful response
    }).promise();


// Delete
    console.log("deleteCertificate"); 
    await setTimeout(1000);
    params = {
        certificateId: certId,                  /* required */
        forceDelete: true
    };
    await iot.deleteCertificate(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(`delete err = ${JSON.stringify(err)}, err.stack = ${err.stack}`);     // an error occurred
        else     console.log(`delete data = ${data}`);                                             // successful response
    }).promise();
```

In the logs, I see stuff like this:

```
INFO updateCertificate
INFO update data = [object Object]
INFO update err = {"message":"Parallel updates to the same record.","code":"InvalidRequestException",
INFO deleteCertificate
INFO delete data = [object Object]
INFO delete err = {"message":"Can't delete!! Certificate has been modified during deletion.",

INFO updateCertificate
INFO update data = [object Object]
INFO update err = {"message":"Parallel updates to the same record.","code":"InvalidRequestException",
INFO deleteCertificate
INFO delete err = {"message":"Can't delete!! Certificate has been modified during deletion.","code":"
INFO DeleteConflictException: Can't delete!! Certificate has been modified during deletion. at Object.extractError ...
```

It seems that the execution is succeeding in general. But why is it running twice? The errors all seem to stem from that root cause - it's not surprising that it's seeing parallel updates given that it's gone and done it twice! And same for trying to delete something that it's literally just finished deleting... Not helpful!